# How to transform triple integral $\iiint_\Omega \sqrt{1- \frac{x^2}{a^2}- \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} }\ dx dy dz$

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, transformation, substitution

I have  stumbled across this triple integral
$$\iiint_\Omega \sqrt{1- \frac{x^2}{a^2}- \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} }\ dx dy dz$$
where
$$\Omega =\left\{(x,y,z)\in{\cal{R}}^3\ \bigg| \ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} \le1 \right\}
$$

I know that I am supposed to use integral transform in which I have to use substitutions. I would substitute $x/a = u, y/b = v, z/c = w$. I can’t find enough examples on how to solve integrals with 3 variables with integral transform.
I really struggled with this integral. Can you guys help me with it?

Comment: Do you have any difficulties in using the spherical coordinates?

Comment: Yes i do have difficulties using and understanding it

Answer (score 4):

Make the variable changes
$x= a u$, $ y= b v$, $z= c w$, and then integrate in spherical coordinates

\begin{align}
&\iiint_{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2} 
 + \frac{z^2}{c^2}\le1 }\sqrt{1- \frac{x^2}{a^2}- \frac{y^2}{b^2} 
 - \frac{z^2}{c^2} }\ dx dy dz \\
=&\ abc \iiint_{u^2 +v^2+w^2\le1 }\sqrt{1- {u^2}- {v^2} 
 - {w^2}}\  dudv dw \\
= &\ 2\pi \ abc\int_0^\pi \int _0^1 \sqrt{1- {\rho^2}}\ \rho^2 \sin\phi \ d\rho d\phi
=\frac{\pi^2}4 abc
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much!